# Introduction as "chapter 0"

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters

I've been looking for an aswer to this, but the keywords I can think about lead me to anwers that are related but opposite to what I need. I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

that is, I want the introduction to have a title, and to have the word "Introduction" where usually you find "Chapter n" (that is exactly what is removed if I use `\chapter*`).

I can control the counter so that the following one will be Chapter 1 as needed, and I can temporarily rename the header with `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Introduction}`, but what I get is "Introduction 0", how can I get rid off that "0"? Of course I want a coherent appearance in the TOC, as here:

[image]

How can I accomplish this? I'd like a solution that works as independently as possible from the document class I'm in, but in case I'd say I need it in "book" or in "octavo".

Thank you very much!

---

A working example could be this, but actually it's *not* working, it does the wrong thing as I have described! I'd *need* some code that outputs like the images I posted!

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,inner=14mm,outer=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Introduction}
\chapter{A wonderful journey}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}
\chapter{Let's go}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...

\chapter{Keep going}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...

\end{document}
```

Comment: With KOMA you could do `\addchap{Introduction}`, but we can't help you much, if you do not provide us with your code (MWE, minimal working example).

Comment: For standard classes, `\chapter*{Intro}` would be more common. But it is hard to say what might happen without seeing the code you used to get this *non-standard* toc appearance.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem?

Comment: @TeXnician and all others: IMHO lesath82 does not only want to remove `Capitolo 0` but replace it by `Introduzione`. This should be printed in addition to the the main heading (argument of `\chapter`) as a prefix line like `Capitolo 0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to have "Introduzione" instead of "Capitolo 0" and also an additional heading, using standard class `book` you could redefine `\@chapapp` to "Introduzione" and `\thechapter` to an empty string before `\chapter`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}% or english instead of italian for an English example
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Prefazione}% or Preface instead of Prefazione for an English example
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Prefazione}% add ToC entry (see comment above to switch to English)
\lipsum

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}% the introduction will be chapter 0
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{}% Get rid of the page number
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@chapapp}{Introduzione}% replace "Chapter" (or "Appendix") by "Introdutione" (use "Introduction" instead of "Introduzione" for an English example)
\makeatother
\chapter{Un viaggio nella matematica}% or "A Trip to Math" in English
\lipsum

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}% bring back the chapter numbers
\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\@chapapp}{\chaptername}\makeatother% and the chapter name
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

This would be enough for the heading:

[image]

But not for the table of contents:

[image]

So you would need an additional package to change the ToC entries.

---

Using a KOMA-Script class you would be able to reconfigure not only the ToC entries but also to define a new chapter command only for the introduction:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}% or \usepackage[english]{babel} for English
\usepackage{mwe}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[%
  style=chapter,% use chapter heading style for the new command
  level=0,% same level as chapter (could also use \chapternumdepth)
  pagestyle=plain,% use page style plain for the starting page like \chapter does
  % following options are only needed, if you are using scrbook before 3.24.2626
  % With KOMA-Script 3.24.2626 or newer you should remove the following 5 lines.
  beforeskip=\dimexpr\csname scr@chapter@beforeskip\endcsname,%
  innerskip=\dimexpr\csname scr@chapter@innerskip\endcsname,%
  afterskip=\dimexpr\csname scr@chapter@afterskip\endcsname,%
  prefixfont=\usekomafont{chapterprefix},%
  font=\usekomafont{chapter},%
  % following options are from tocbasic but with prefix `toc`:
  tocstyle=chapter,% use chapter entry style for the ToC entry
  tocindent=0pt,% do not indent the ToC entry
  tocnumwidth=8em,% enough for "Introduzione" or "Introduction"
  tocpagenumberbox=\underlinepagenumberbox% use a special kind of page number (see below)
  ]{introduction}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  tocnumwidth=8em,% enough for "Capitolo" or "Chapter" + Number
  tocentrynumberformat=\chapapp\enskip,% add "Chapter" before the number of the ToC entry
  tocpagenumberbox=\underlinepagenumberbox
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=0pt]{section}% don't indent section entries to the ToC
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=2.3em]{subsection}% not used in this example
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\sectiontocdepth}% show only chapter and section in ToC (like the image in the question)

\makeatletter
% The following command is used to print the page numbers of chapter
% and introduction entries to the ToC. It does not only format the
% page number but additionally add a rule below the entry.
\newcommand*{\underlinepagenumberbox}[1]{%
  \makebox[\@pnumwidth][r]{#1}% page number as usual
  \nobreak
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}[0pt][2\dp\strutbox]{\rule{\columnwidth}{.5pt}}}% rule
}
\makeatother

\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\Large\mdseries}% make the prefix line of the headings less strong

\renewcommand*{\theintroduction}{Introduzione}% text instead of number (use "Introduction" for an English example)

\begin{document}
\addchap{Prefazione}% use "Preface" for an English example
\lipsum

\tableofcontents

\introduction{Un viaggio nella matematica}% or \introduction{Trip to Math} for an English example
\lipsum

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

This would result in a ToC:

[image]

and an introduction:

[image]

Very similar to the images you've shown in your question. For all the commands, like `\DeclareNewSectionCommand` or `\RedeclareSectionCommand` see [the English KOMA-Script manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) or [the German KOMA-Script manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf). Note, some options (all with prefix `toc`) are inherited from the TOC style `tocline` of package `tocbasic`. The KOMA-Script manual has a chapter about `tocbasic`.

---

Here is one more example using other KOMA-Script commands to do almost the same but without the need of a new chapter command:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
% scrbook internally does not use \@chapapp directly but \chapapp
% So we can redefine it to change the result depending on whether counter
% chapter is 0 or -1 or (else) > 0:
\renewcommand*{\chapapp}{%
  \ifcase -\value{chapter}\relax
    \introductionname
  \or
    \prefacename
  \else
    \@chapapp
  \fi
}
% But \thechapter should output nothing, if counter chapter is <= 0
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{%
  \ifnum \value{chapter}>\z@\arabic{chapter}\else\fi
}
% We do want to have \chapapp also before the number in the ToC entry.
% So we add it, if the first argument (this is the number argument) of
% \addchaptertocentry is not empty. If it is empty, we do not need to change
% anything:
\let\orig@addchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry% Todo: better use letltxmacro
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}{\orig@addchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}}{%
    \orig@addchaptertocentry{\chapapp\nobreakspace#1}{#2}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\introductionname}{Introduction}% The new name for introduction

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  tocnumwidth=8em,% enough for "Chapter" + Number or "Introduction" or "Preface"
  tocpagenumberbox=\underlinepagenumberbox
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=0pt]{section}% don't indent section entries to the ToC
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=2.3em]{subsection}% not used in this example
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\sectiontocdepth}% show only chapter and section in ToC (like the image in the question)

\makeatletter
% The following command is used to print the page numbers of chapter
% and introduction entries to the ToC. It does not only format the
% page number but additionally add a rule below the entry.
\newcommand*{\underlinepagenumberbox}[1]{%
  \makebox[\@pnumwidth][r]{#1}% page number as usual
  \nobreak
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}[0pt][2\dp\strutbox]{\rule{\columnwidth}{.5pt}}}% rule
}
\makeatother

\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\Large\mdseries}% make the prefix line of the headings less strong

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{-2}% We start with a preface
\chapter{About how to do it a bit more complicate}
\lipsum

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Trip to math}
\lipsum

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

This results in the following preface, table of contents, introduction and first chapter pages:

[image][image]

For this last example even KOMA-Script 3.22 would be enough.

Comment: Wow, that seems to output exactly as I need. I hoped in something less complicated, I see a lot of things I still don't know, but I'll go trough your answer to understand it in detail as much as I can!

Comment: Amazing, thank you! It is indeed a lot of stuff for "just" removing the zero after "Introduction" (the only flaw of my code).

Comment: Well no, my code has only the chapter number in the TOC, not the complete "Chapter n"

Comment: @lesath82: In the second example the "Chapter" is added by option `tocentrynumberformat=\chapapp\enskip` of `\RedeclareSectionCommand[…]{chapter}`. This does work independent from the language. If you don't want it, remove the option. If you want it, you need the the option. If you remove it, you should also remove the change of `tocnumwidth` (otherwise the result would be ugly).

Comment: The KOMA-Script example needs at least KOMA-Script version 3.24.2626. This is not yet on CTAN but can be installed from the [KOMA-Script website](https://komascript.de/node/1801).  With the current KOMA-Script version 3.23 you still have to set `beforeskip`, `afterskip`,  `font`, ... for the new defined chapter command.

Comment: @esdd Thank you for your clarification. I've added additional lines to make the solution compatible with KOMA-Script 3.23 (current CTAN release, also available in the MiKTeX repository and the official TeX Live 2017 repository).